# JasperReports Ireport Subdataset get data with SQL query

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to get data from SQL query in Subdataset. The SQL query with parameters is work well. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM voc_agents WHERE id= $P{id_voc_agent}
```

But it doesn't work without parameters:

```
SELECT * FROM voc_agents
```

The dataset run is P{REPORT_CONNECTION}

And I get an error in Ireport :

```
Error filling print... java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: report3_Table32Dataset321_1374560092779_964952 (wrong name: report3_1374560092779_964952) null 
Setting up the file resolver...  Set Dataset: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignDataset
```

How can I get all data using SQL query without parameters? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons for `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: **** (wrong name: *****)` is a version difference between the Jaspersoft studio used to design report and the Jasper jar used during runtime.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of $P{REPORT_CONNECTION} you could try giving the subreport it's own database connection. For odbc that would be:

```
 java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:hostname", "user", "password")
```

Comment: Is it an answer on a question: `How can I get all data using SQL query without parameters?`?

Comment: Yes it is. It's worth trying.